# uses for the words BROAD & WIDE

Tags: word-meaning

could anybody tell me please if there is a rule which may indicate us when to use "BROAD" and when to use "WIDE? For example: I know it is correct to say "broad daylight" but is it wrong to say "wide daylight"? 2nd Example: "world wide" it is correct, but what about, "world broad" 3er example: "Wide-awake" which is correct, but "Broad-awake" is it correct? Diccionares are unable to explain this or if there is a rule. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Broad daylight" and "Wide awake" are idiomatic expressions. You can't change them. That's just how they are!

**Broad daylight** means

> The time when everybody can see what is happening

For example, *The crime happened in broad daylight*

**Wide awake** means *Fully awake*. It also means a hat. Revise your dictionary for more information.

**Worldwide** is a word. We don't write it separately. It's an adjective, sometimes an adverb. For example, *He is famous worldwide*

In many contexts, *wide* and *broad* are synonym and are interchangeable.

Comment: You might want to copy and paste your answer in the "older" question. I don't think this question will resist deletion.